# Why are symplectic manifolds and Riemannian manifolds so different?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

They seem superficially similar in some ways

1) both have a given two tensor on the tangent space
2) if we choose a hamiltonian function for the symplectic manifold then both give a canonical mapping from the tangent space to the cotangent space
3) they both give a canonical flow of the manifold and we can interpretate hamiltonian flow as geodesic flow

But the worlds are COMPLETELY different

1) riemannian manifolds have lots of local invariants, symplectic manifolds all look locally the same
2) it is always possible to put a riemannian tensor on a given manifold, symplectic manifolds are much rarer

Riemannian geometry provides a reasonable measure of length, symplectic geometry provides a reasonable definition of area. Why do these lead to such different theories?

Comment: You could ask a simpler question of why nondegenerate bilinear forms that are symmetric vs. alternating are so different: the first type can exist in any dimension while the second type only exists in even dimensions.

Comment: I think you already answered it: the similarities are superficial. There's no reason to believe they *should* give remotely similar theories.

Comment: Note that you require an extra equation $d\omega = 0$, while in RG the metric do not satisfies any equation.

Comment: As KCd suggested, start with linear algebra and in the simplest case, dimension 2. The inner product has $O(2)$ as the group of symmetries, while the area form has $SL(2,R)$. The latter is much bigger (by any measure). This is the first hint for why the group of symplectomorphisms is much larger than the group of self-isometries.

Comment: If you just want area, a non-degenerate 2-form is enough. To the best of my knowledge, very little has been done in almost symplectic geometry. The fact that $d\omega = 0$ is huge... it's analogous to asking that your Riemannian metric be flat. See a discussion by Ben Webster at the Secret Blogging Seminar for his take on this: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/why-do-symplectic-manifolds-need-to-be-closed/

Comment: In Riemannian geometry you get gradient flows. In symplectic geometry you get Hamiltonian flows, where the vector field is the gradient with a "twist". Here the Hamiltonian is conserved, unlike the gradient flow where it increases.